# How to Restore PostgreSQL dump file into SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I get updated dump file of PostgreSQL database everyday. How do I restore that file into a SQL Server database ?

Is there any other way I can straight transfer the data from  PostgreSQL to SQL server 2012? ETL tools?

Comment: The dump file you get from Postgres can not be "restored" to SQL Server. You will have to use some kind of ETL tool (or just export the data as CSV/Text from Postgres and then bulk import that into SQL Server e.g. using `bcp`)

Comment: Probably you need tool like [Full Convert](https://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert). Specify what you want to migrate only data or data + stored procedures and functions??

Comment: Just wanted to get the data from PostgreSQL database and transfer to the SQL and create reports using SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using GDAL.

A script similar to the below will connect to SQL Server and transfer the support.support table from PostgreSQL, this one is also re-projecting the data into ESPG:27700.

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -update -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=servername;database=databasename;UID=username;PWD=********" -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=databasenaem user=postgres password=*******" public.support -lco OVERWRITE=yes -lco SCHEMA=public  -a_srs EPSG:27700 -progress
```

My favorite guide to installing GDAL is https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows if you have not used it before.

You maybe interested in using paid for software such as [spectralcord full convert](https://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert)
or [db convert](https://dbconvert.com/mssql/postgre/) I am sure there are many more out there that you can search for.

There are other ways such as using python that I am not to familiar with but I would like to know more about too.